# Email using php will not send when $headers added

Tags: php

I'm trying to send an email currently works fine. but once I add this line It won't email anymore.

```
$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
mail("anton@sci5.com", $subject, $message, $from, $headers )
```

Basically when  I add `$headers` to my `mail();` it won't work but if I remove the `$header` it sends out my mail but html is not being rendered.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my code.

```
$subject = "E-newsletter Signup";

$message = "$todayis [EST] \n
            From: $firstname $lastname ($email)\n
            $firstname $lastname has subscribe for the ff. e-newsletters:\n
           " ;

if (!empty($ivpump1)) { $message .= "$ivpump1\n"; }
if (!empty($fetal1)) { $message .= "$fetal1\n"; }
if (!empty($biomed1)) { $message .= "$biomed1\n"; }

$message.= "<br /><br /><br />
            <p><b>From Webpage :</b> $fromWebpage </p>
            <p><b>From Google Keyword :</b> $refKeyword</p>
            <p><b>Referring Page :</b> $refPage</p>
            <p><b>From IP Address :</b> $endUserIP</p>";

$from = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

mail("anton@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $from, $headers );
header("Location: http://www.site.com/thank-you-settings.html");
```

Comment: mail, takes 4 not 5 arguments, the from should be in the headers

Comment: @dagon: it does take 5 args, but headers is the 4th. 'From:' is simply a header like any other: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: correct, i forgot -f, dont see that much theses days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `From: $from\r\n` to your headers before the `Content-Type` in the quotes and getting rid of the `from` argument when you call the mail function. Unless you set a default `from` in php.ini, or use the `additional_parameters` argument (the fifth one), if you want to set the 'from' value, the function has four mandatory arguments, the last of which is `headers`. It seems that your `from` is meeting the requirements of the `headers` argument, but once you add the fifth argument you are incorrectly using the function.

Comment: let me clarify: unless you set a default with php.ini or use the `additional parameters` parameter, it has only four _mandatory_ parameters.

Comment: Three arguments can be used, but unless a default value for "from" is set with php.ini, a custom 'from' value won't be able to be used.

Comment: you still say there are "four mandatory arguments" when there are only 3

Comment: I said only four _if_ a custom "from" is desired. And, as written in the question, one is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to review the signature of the mail function http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

It is `mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers)`. You are calling it incorrectly.

`$headers` needs to be:

```
$headers = "From: me@me.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'headers' and the 'from' must be part of the same variable, try this:

```
<?php
$mime_boundary=md5(time());
$headers .= 'From: My Email <me@company.com>' . "\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'. "\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$mime_boundary."\"". "\n"; 

$msg .= "--".$mime_boundary. "\n";
$msg .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1". "\n";
$msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit". "\n\n";
$msg .= $textmessage . "\n\n";

$msg .= "--".$mime_boundary. "\n";
$msg .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"".$filename."\"". "\n";
$msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64". "\n";
$msg .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"". "\n\n";
$msg .= chunk_split(base64_encode($doc)) . "\n\n";
$msg .= "--".$mime_boundary."--". "\n\n";

mail("anton@sci5.com", $subject, $msg ,$headers );

?>
```

In the example you send a PDF, you can send images or any other file, just need to send the right `"Content-Type:`  like application/pdf for pdf

More information: http://rob.sun3.org/archives/107

Comment: where is the op sending images in his email?

Comment: In the link he can see how to add images, the example shows a pdf

Comment: so 99% of the example is irrelevant.

Comment: Ok, good -1 for not trying to see the whole reference, bravo! Good guidance for the op. I'll add it for @Dagon

Comment: One small gripe here, please use the proper opening `<?php` tag. `<?` is not a good practice as it isn't enabled on most servers, and it's use is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

1. Correct Signature function of the mail.

   ```
   mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers)
   ```
2. $header needs to be:

   ```
   $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
   ```
3. A good example of Html email with php:
         http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/
4. If html rendering not works now then the reason is:

   A lot of email clients, unfortunately, do not respect html or css files in the header.
   Everything needs to be inline. This problem occurs with gmail and outlook as well.